# Hide posts belongs to few categories in homepage

Tags: posts, categories, homepage

Currently I am using all the latest posts are displaying in the homepage settings. But now I need to hide few specific categories to be displayed in the homepage.

All the post belongs to those specific categories should not display in the homepage.

Anyone have an idea how should I do that ?

**Edited:**

I am using following code to retrieve posts to display in the homepage,

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; 
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts( $args );
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).
This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run.

For excluding **category id** `32` and `39` from homepage, you can setup a function like this.

```
function wpse_exclude_categories( $query ) {

    if ( is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-32,-39' );
    }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_exclude_categories', 1 );
```

**EDIT**

Although I would strongly recommend you to use `WP_Query`. But you can change your code to exclude category posts with `query_posts`.

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => '-32,-33',
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

Comment: I apply this change, but the posts are still there in the homepage, I paste this page in the bottom of template function.php, is that the issue ?

Comment: You must have a custom `WP_Query` for displaying post on homepage or may be cache.

Comment: @JanithChinthana Did you change the values to your exact value, and are you using build in categories or a custom taxonomy. The code above does work, we all use it

Comment: yest, i did. and I used build in categories, but still I am check whether there is custom `WP_Query` for displaying the posts

Comment: I think you should [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/193937/edit) and post the code responsible for displaying homepage posts.

Comment: I found that it is using `query_posts` to retrieve the posts, so it is not `WP_Query`, I have edited it, please check

Comment: I have filed an edit. Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Roberthue it works, but why does your first answer doesn't work as it is widely accepted, anyway thanks

Comment: `query_posts` is really only for modifying the current loop and I think it overwrites the main query object. That's why you should never use `query_posts`. Use `get_posts` or `WP_Query` instead. You must read [the differences between these three](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/).

Comment: `query_posts` is really only for **nothing**. It does overwrite the main query object, thus breaking it. Do a `var_dump($wp_query)` before `query_posts( '&s=crap' );` and then again after it and check the results. Also do `var_dump(is_search());` before and after your `query_posts` call. You will see how really bad `query_posts` really is